# Linux kernel make keeps overwriting my .config /dropping changes

Tags: linux-kernel, make, build

I’m trying to build a custom ARM kernel on a BeagleBone black wireless. I’m using [this kernel as a start](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.9.tar.gz)

I copied the current `.config` file (`make localmodconfig`) and edited it manually to add support for the built in WLAN module (changes from [there](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/WL18xx_Platform_Integration_Guide)).

When I run `make uImage` or other targets, I’m always prompted questions. After answering, the `.config` is overwritten and some changes are gone. I also tried `make olddefconfig` which showed roughly the same results without the questions.

*Changes made:*

```
CONFIG_WLAN=y
CONFIG_WIRELESS=y
CONFIG_WIRELESS_EXT=y
CONFIG_WL12XX_PLATFORM_DATA=y

CONFIG_KEYS=y
CONFIG_SECURITY=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO=y

CONFIG_CRYPTO_ARC4=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_ECB=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_MICHAEL_MIC=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_RNG=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_AEAD=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_CCM=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_GCM=y

CONFIG_RFKILL=y

CONFIG_REGULATOR_FIXED_VOLTAGE=y
CONFIG_CRC7=y

# The following are needed for soft AP
CONFIG_NETFILTER=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_ADVANCED=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XTABLES=y
CONFIG_NF_DEFRAG_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_PROC_COMPAT=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_IPTABLES=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_FILTER=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_LOG=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_NEEDED=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_MASQUERADE=y

CONFIG_INPUT_UINPUT=y

# Enable Ethernet-WLAN Bridge
CONFIG_NETFILTER=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_ADVANCED=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_NETFILTER=y
CONFIG_STP=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_IGMP_SNOOPING=y
CONFIG_LLC=y
CONFIG_INPUT_UINPUT=y
CONFIG_HAS_IOMEM=y
CONFIG_HAS_IOPORT=y
CONFIG_HAS_DMA=y
CONFIG_NLATTR=y
CONFIG_AVERAGE=y
```

How can I and can I skip/avoid this? Do I need a different kernel? Or do something else? Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Linux kernel make keeps overwriting my .config /dropping changes

That indicates that you probably do not have a valid **.config** file for building a kernel.
Seems like you have not followed the guide you mentioned:

```
It is often easiest to start with a base default configuration and then customize it for you use case if needed.
```

If you had actually used a "*base default configuration*" (e.g. refer to the latter part of this answer) instead of a mystery "*current **.config** file*", then you probably would not have run into such issues.

---

> I copied the current .config file (make localmodconfig) and edited it manually to add support for the built in Wlan module

No, that's not the proper way of configuring a Linux kernel.
Using a **.config** file from an older kernel version will probably have deprecated config names, and simply should be avoided if you're not sure of what you're doing.
Otherwise, "*if you want to carry your existing configuration to a
new version with minimal work, use "make oldconfig", which will
only ask you for the answers to new questions*" (quote from the Linux kernel README file).

Unless you really know what you are doing, direct editing of the **.config** file will probably result in missing dependent and requisite configuration options.

---

> Do I need a different kernel? Or do something else?

You have chosen to use the mainline kernel, which does not have a defconfig file specifically for the Beaglebone Black SBC.
You could start with a generic build for a TI AM335x board, and then boot with the **am335x-boneblack.dtb** Device Tree file

Start over with the shell command

```
make mrproper
```

or

```
make distclean
```

Verify that your toolchain (cross compiler, etc.) is in your PATH, e.g.

```
echo $PATH
```

Set the environment variable for the architecture:

```
export ARCH=arm
```

Set the environment variable for the toolchain prefix according to what you have installed, e.g.

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

Note the trailing hyphen.

Install a generic kernel configuration for the TI Sitara product line (in place of a specific Beaglebone Black defconfig).

```
make omap2plus_defconfig
```

Customize the kernel build using a *proper* configuration tool:

```
make menuconfig
```

Then build the kernel image, loadable modules, and Device Tree blob:

```
make uImage
make modules
make am335x-boneblack.dtb
```

More details can be found in the README file in the Linux kernel source.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think its the same kernel version(as far as i know, i dont have it with ne now). Altough make oldconfig does prompt with new config options. Ill check again. But how can i add for example: `CONFIG_WL12XX_PLATFORM_DATA` if its dropped? Isn't it supported by the kernel? I found the drivers for it in the drivers directory.

Comment: CONFIG_WL12XX_PLATFORM_DATA does not look like a valid symbol.  Why WL12xx?  The guide you referenced is for WL18xx.  What "drivers" did you find?

Comment: It is a WL18XX but the guide for it told me to enable that. It might be a mistake. But why is it dropped? Maybe it depends on something. I'll try to find the option somewhere in the config tool, but do you have an idea how i can fit this option in? Thanks again!

Comment: A grep for the string "WL12XX_PLATFORM_DATA" in the 4.9 kernel source finds zero occurrences.  You can't enable something that doesn't exist, and it's a waste of time since it's not used anywhere in 4.9.

Comment: Yes so do i need a special kernel or can i expect(fair chance) that it works it the device tree is configured properly and the options that are available are enabled?

Comment: Try configuring the 4.9 kernel with "Generic IEEE 802.11 Networking Stack (mac80211)" and "TI wl18xx support".  And fixup the board's .dts file.  Look at **am335x-evm.dts** for possible example of WL18xx node.